# How do you find the derivative of the following?

Tags: derivatives, linear-transformations

My main issue is that I do not know specifically, anything about the subject of differentiation.

> Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix and $F_A:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be the associated linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. What is $DF_A$?

$D$ is the symbol for "derivative" in my notes. It is equivalent to, say in the one-variable case $\frac{df}{dx}$ but since there are no common widely known notation in the several-variable case, my notes uses $Df$ to denote the derivative of $f$.

My understanding is that $F_A$ can be represented as a form of matrix, which is $A$, if I interpreted the question correctly. But then, $DF_A$ is essentially the derivative of $A$, but I don't know anything about the entries of $A$. How am I suppose to differentiate it, so to find $DF_A$? Or is there a mistake in my understanding?

Please tell me how, thank you

Comment: Just so you know, your book's notation is called [Euler's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Euler.27s_notation) and it's used in differential equations a lot.

Comment: I think you're missing a very important concept. The one of differentiability of a function from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$. Do you know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear map $Df:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$\frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(h)\|}{\|h\|} = O(\|h\|).$$

If $f$ is linear, what is the obvious choice of $Df$? (Try expanding $f(x+h)$ in the above.) The result actually holds quite generally in Banach spaces (and linear maps on them) for the same reasons.

Comment: Hi, sorry, what is the $O(||h||)$ there at the end of the equation?

Comment: That's just big O notation; effectively it says that the stuff on the left hand side goes to zero at least as fast as $h$ does. If you prefer, just put a limit on the left hand side and equate it to zero as so:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0.$$

If you're having trouble seeing it, try the case of $m=1=n$.

Comment: I apologize if I am not understanding you correctly,  but so, by the hint that $f$ is linear, $Df$ should be some constant...? Is that your point...?

Comment: No. $f(x+h) = f(x)+f(h)$ so $f(x+h)-f(x) = f(h)$, leaving you with $f(h)-Df(h)$ in the numerator. $f$ is linear. $Df$ is linear...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification..I honestly might be very lost than I thought; I am not sure what the answer to the question "what is $DF_A$?" would look like. I'm sure "it's a linear map" is not the answer, so from your generous hints I assume some rearranging of terms is needed to find $Df(h)=$? Sorry I am so confused...

Comment: Yes they want you to get an expression for the derivative. There is a very nice solution based on what I've said.

Comment: Is it that $Df$ can be given as a matrix where the $i,j$th entry has $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial f_j}$...? from $m$ to $n$ gives a $n \times m$ matrix with such entries...and that is $Df$.

Comment: You're thinking of the Jacobian. I'll just spell it out for you and let you figure out why what I said is correct. $f=Df$.